# Stacklayout label spacing - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a stacklayout which has three labels inside it. But when i display it there gap between those labels. I want to avoid the space. Can anybody help me which property will avoid this problem.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use the **Spacing** property of the **StackLayout** to adjust spacing between items.

The following illustrates this:-

```
        StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout()
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Spacing = 0
        };

        Label objLabel1 = new Label();
        objLabel1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        objLabel1.Text = "Red";
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel1);

        Label objLabel2 = new Label();
        objLabel2.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
        objLabel2.Text = "Green";
        objLabel2.Font = Font.OfSize("Arial", 48);
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel2);

        Label objLabel3 = new Label();
        objLabel3.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
        objLabel3.Text = "Blue";
        objLabel3.Font = Font.OfSize("Arial", 48);
        objStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel3);
```

Comment: I have used spacing.Even then there is spacing in between

Comment: Are you trying the example above, or something in your own application?  What platform also are you trying this on?

Comment: You should create a small example that demonstrates your issue and then maybe someone will be able to help you specifically with the issue your experiencing, as the **Spacing** property does control the gap between items in a **StackLayout** control.

Comment: A notice - StackLayout Spacing gives noticeably different results on iOS and Android. I had to use 2x larger spacing to achieve the same look on iOS as on Android